# How to queue requests and execute in server side in asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api2

I have methods in server side that use a shared data and I need to synchronize the data access between different request. E.g.

```
BrowserClient1_Calling_Method1()
{
    //This should be an XHR call and it waits for the result. 
}

BrowserClient2_Calling_Method2()
{
    //This should be an XHR call and it waits for the result. 
}
```

And at server side I have two methods that need to be called one by one.

```
//When ever this method is called, put it in some sort of queue so that 
//Method1 and Method2 gets executed one by one.  
Server_Method1()
{
    //Access the SHARED data
}


//When ever this method is called, put it in some sort of queue so that 
//Method1 and Method2 gets executed one by one.
Server_Method2()
{
    //Access the SHARED data
}
```

so, my question is , how do I use some soft of `ConcurrentQueue` and execute the server methods one by one and `make client unaware of such the queue.` **From client perspective it should be like any other XHR request**.

I tried using `BlockingCollection` in c# but not sure what sort of pattern should I follow.

Please note that I could use "lock" inside the Server methods but I wanted to do without having to use `locks`.

Answer (score 0):

when your are using shared variables the safest and best thing to do is using lock patterns(there are multiple option to handle this)

for second part of your question best way is use to async method so your client didng aware of your queue and after their request executed you can send them signal to show related response (use signal-r)

if you need more detail please tell me to describe you each section